# obtener texto de un span dentro de un div - Jquery

Tags: jquery, selectores

HTML

```
<div id="mdCalendar-body" class="mdCalendar-body">
<table class="cal-table">
<thead><tr><td class="days-title">L</td><td class="days-title">M</td><td class="days-title">M</td><td class="days-title">J</td><td class="days-title">V</td><td class="days-title">S</td><td class="days-title">D</td></tr></thead>


<tbody class="bodyCalendartable">
    <tr>
        <td class="day not-day" data-month="10" data-year="2018" data-day="01" data-maxday="3">
        <label>1</label>
        <span class="precio">3,879</span>
        <span class="llegada">Llegada</span>
        <span class="final">Salida</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>    
</table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '.day', function () {
            rangeDatePaquete("#MDcalendar-container", $(this));

        });




var rangeDatePaquete = function (id, x) {
        var koin = $(id).find(".cal-table").find(".bodyCalendartable");

        var fday = getDate(x.attr("data-day") + "/" + x.attr("data-month") + "/" + x.attr("data-year"));
        var mxd = x.attr("data-maxday");/// recupera el valor de dias que contempla

        koin.find(".day,.day-old").removeClass("dateHover").removeClass("dateHoverEnd").removeClass("dateHoverDanger").removeClass("dateHoverStart").removeClass("base-cHover").removeClass("base-bHover");// limpia
        if (!x.hasClass("not-day")) {
            var type = x.attr("class");
            var res = type.split(" ");
            console.log(res[1]);

        }
    }
```

En la funcion rangeDate, quiero recuperar el texto que tiene el span .precio, sé que es por selectores jquery, yo intenté esto en la función rangeDate

```
var price = $(x+"> span.precio").text();
```

pero no me funciona y creo que es por la sintaxis que no estoy escribiendo correctamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según veo, `x` contiene el elemento donde se hace el evento `mouseover` que es el `<td>` con la clase `day`, cuando tratas de obtener la clase de esta forma:

```
var price = $(x+"> span.precio").text();
```

`x` devuelve el objeto completo `day`. Entonces, si quieres obtener la clase sería de esta forma (debesprevenir cuando el elemento tiene mas de una clase, debes concatenar las clases con puntos):

```
price = $("."+x.attr('class').split(/[ ,]+/).join('.')+"> span.precio").text();
```

el selector seria algo así:

> .day.not-day > span.precio

Otra forma de hacerlo es con children:

```
var price = x.children("span.precio").text();
```

```js
$('body').on('mouseover', '.day', function() {
  rangeDatePaquete("#MDcalendar-container", $(this));
});

var rangeDatePaquete = function(id, x) {
    var price = x.children("span.precio").text();
    console.log("con children: "+price);
    
    price = "";
    price = $("."+x.attr('class').split(/[ ,]+/).join('.')+"> span.precio").text();
    console.log("con class: "+price);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mdCalendar-body" class="mdCalendar-body">
  <table class="cal-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="days-title">L</td>
        <td class="days-title">M</td>
        <td class="days-title">M</td>
        <td class="days-title">J</td>
        <td class="days-title">V</td>
        <td class="days-title">S</td>
        <td class="days-title">D</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody class="bodyCalendartable">
      <tr>
        <td class="day not-day" data-month="10" data-year="2018" data-day="01" data-maxday="3">
          <label>1</label>
          <span class="precio">3,879</span>
          <span class="llegada">Llegada</span>
          <span class="final">Salida</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No me marca error, pero no me muestra nada cuando imprimo en la consola price

Comment: revisa la respuesta, funciona con las dos soluciones que te he propuesto

Comment: sin duda alguna, no conocia el selector children, todo el tiempo usé el "menor que"